# Android: ListView last item acts weird

Tags: android, android-listview, selecteditem

I have a custom adapter and I have title and content shown with maxlines and minlines.
However it only works for every item except the last.

First few items
[image: Android ListView Last Item]

The last item
[image: Android ListView Last Item 2]

As you can see the last item has no title, but that is **NOT** a problem. It is invisible if length is zero.

First of all it ignores the text color thats not even being set in the Adapter but in the actual .xml. If i press that item it gets the correct color until the longpress actions kicks in. Plus its ignoring the maxLines/minLines.

**The last item has the same content as the one with title "Another bacon."**

```
 .... getView() in BaseAdapter

            hint.setMaxLines( 3 );

            if ( item.getTitle().length() < 1 ) {

                hint.setSingleLine( false );
                hint.setMinLines( !cards_ui ? 3 : 1 );

            } else {

                hint.setSingleLine( true );
                hint.setMinLines( 1 );
                hint.setMaxLines( cards_ui ? 3 : 1 );
            }
```

from item xml

```
<LinearLayout ... >

     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/list_item_title"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="5"
          android:paddingLeft="6dp"
          android:paddingRight="6dp"
          android:textSize="20sp"
          android:textColor="@color/black_lite"
          android:textColorHint="@color/black_lite"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:maxLines="1"
          android:maxEms="10"
          android:ellipsize="end"
          android:hint=""
          android:text=""
          android:textIsSelectable="false" />

     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/list_item_content"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="10"
          android:paddingLeft="6dp"
          android:paddingRight="6dp"
          android:paddingBottom="10dp"
          android:text=""
          android:textSize="15sp"
          android:textColor="@color/black_light"
          android:textColorHint="@color/black_light"
          android:maxLines="3"
          android:ellipsize="end"
          android:textIsSelectable="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

ListView

```
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_selector"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:columnWidth="120dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/grid_spacing"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:padding="@dimen/grid_spacing"
            android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/grid_spacing"
            />
```

So, why is my last item getting another 'style'? There is nothing in my code that is selecting any item and I tried changing the list_selector to transparent but no difference.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using layout_weight and a vertical orientation (list is vertical), then you need to set the height to `0dp` so it gets calculated automatically.

In your example you are trying to provide the title **5/15** of the total height and the content with **10/15**.

Perhaps that is not what you wanted because a list item should generally take up as much space as it needs so `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` is more than enough and weight should be removed.

Comment: I removed the weight but no difference. Isn't the problem the amount of lines?

Comment: @JonasB what adapter are you using? Please post the code where you instantiate it.